# Firestore Realtime Listener equivalent of "Child_Added"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out a solution for the Firestore realtime listeners. I know you can listen to changes and in onSnapshot see what was added, removed, changed.. but is there a way to just listen to additions?

I don't like how anytime there is a change in data, or a new document is added, the query retrieves every single piece of data.. Feels like unnescary data transfer.. especially if you were using the application on a 3G Network

Is that a legitimate concern? or is the query returning negligible data? I just want to get the "new" additions to the collection

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
  // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
  const newValue = snap.data();

  // access a particular field as you would any JS property
  const name = newValue.name;

  // perform desired operations ...
});
```

Comment: He's not talking about listening a document, he want's to listen to the new added children of a specific collections.